# How do I access Configuration.h?

Tags: marlin, arduino-mega-2650, tevo-tarantula

I am very new to 3D printing and I am trying to adjust my firmware. I use the Arduino IDE 1.8.12.

I downloaded the firmware from GitHub that suits my printer, but every time that I try to open the `marlin.ino` file within, it opens in the Arduino with only the blue "marlin" tab. It doesn't load the other tabs such as `Configuration.h` and `Configuration_adv.h`.

I have watched a few YouTube videos, and in all of them, these tabs seem to open automatically.

Thank you very much for any help, I've been struggling to figure this out.

Comment: Did you download Marlin 2.0.x and opened it an older Arduino IDE? Older versions of Arduino IDE do not work with directory structure layout of Marlin 2.0.x.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have arduino 1.8.12 and Im trying to open Marlin 2.0.x

Comment: You can also use VSCode and PlatformIO plug-in

Comment: Does this help to answer your question? [Updating Marlin Firmware - Step by Step Guide](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/12153/updating-marlin-firmware-step-by-step-guide)

Comment: Can you copy the files to a "real" PC and open the  .h files in a text editor?