# How to probe twice while mesh bed leveling with a BLTouch setup?

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling, bltouch

I am using an Ender 3 (v1.1.4) with Marlin 1.1.X bugfix installed. Also BLTouch v3.1 is used. The probe is deployed once only while mesh bed leveling.

How can I make the probe deploy twice at every point? Where am I supposed to change the code for it?

Please explain in detail if possible as I am not familiar with the coding part?

Answer (score 1):

For the 1.1.x (1.1.9) bugfix firmware version, the multiple probing is defined in the [configuration.h file](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/bugfix-1.1.x/Marlin/Configuration.h#L795).

```
// The number of probes to perform at each point.
//   Set to 2 for a fast/slow probe, using the second probe result.
//   Set to 3 or more for slow probes, averaging the results.
//#define MULTIPLE_PROBING 2
```

You should change the configuration to include the multiple probing by uncommenting the line:

```
#define MULTIPLE_PROBING 2
```

---

*Note that there is question: "[Updating Marlin Firmware - Step by Step Guide](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/12153/updating-marlin-firmware-step-by-step-guide)" that shows how you should modify the sources.*

*How to compile and upload/install the compiled binary on your printer controller board depends on the controller board version and type.*