# How to properly run a PID Tuning and update the firmware?

Tags: marlin, knowledgebase, pid

The [Firmware Step-by-step guide](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/12153/updating-marlin-firmware-step-by-step-guide) remarks to only mess with PID-Tuning settings in the firmware when you *know what you are doing*. Apparently, defining those settings in the firmware is a somewhat involved process, so this begs the question:

**How do you acquire the PID-tuning settings properly and update the boars of a printer so it retains these settings** through power cycling?

Let's for simplicity assume there is a Marlin Firmware or a derivative using the same command codes is installed, so we can assume all the commands from the [Marlin G-code repository](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G000-G001.html) work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 0: Terminal connection

To do any work on the settings of the board, you'll need to run a Terminal - for setting that up, please see the [relevant question here.](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10573/what-is-a-printer-console-terminal)

### Step 1: What do we have?

The second step is dissecting the settings that are set already. To do so, send `M503` to read the relevant settings from the SRAM of the board and display them in the Terminal of your choice.

### Step 2: Try a PID Autotune

To run a PID Autotune, just start by sending this for your first hotend to enforce a 3-cycle PID tuning for the 200 °C region:

[`M303 C3 S200`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M303.html)

For your second hotend, you'd send `M303 C3 E1 S200` - the E-value is 0-indexed and defaults to 0 for the first hotend, so E1 is the second hotend.

For your heatbed (and PLA) you send `M303 C3 E-1 S60` as -1 is the function dependant value for the heated bed.

### Step 3: Setting the PID settings

After having obtained the PID settings from running the tuning cycle, we need to send those to the chips. To do so use [`M301`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M301.html) for a hotend and [`M304`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M304.html) for the heatbed, using the given values from step 2 as parameters.

Note again, that if you have more than one hotend, you absolutely need to have an E-value if you try to set the second hotend, as the default value is, again, E0 for the first hotend.

### Step 4: Saving

To properly save the values into the EEPROM - provided it is enabled - is to just send one command to finalize:

- [`M500`](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M500.html)

If your EEPROM is not enabled, you'd need to take the line you wrote for Step 3 and insert that into your pre-print G-code, thus overwriting the PID settings in the SRAM before each print.