# Increase the measuring points on Ender 3 S1 Pro

Tags: creality-ender-3

I have a Creality Ender 3 S1 Pro with the factory board and firmware. Is there any option to increase the number of leveling points? Since it is not an open Marlin code, I have no access to the firmware source to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to change this in the firmware. It has to be changed, built and uploaded. Marlin is a free firmware, and there are lots of tutorials, forks and configurations for the Ender 3 S1 Pro to use as a start. We even have a [rough step by step guide](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/12153/updating-marlin-firmware-step-by-step-guide) for working on that.