# Is Marlin 2.0 actually needed for Automatic Bed Leveling using FreeABL?

Tags: creality-ender-3, firmware, automatic-bed-leveling

I need Automatic Bed Leveling (ABL). I have seen this: [FreeABL - the ultra cheap (free) ABL for Ender 3](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3468254/). However, after reading the description, I found out that I need to flash the firmware.

I had a lot of problems with this, so is it actually needed?

Comment: Are you trying to link to a particular comment in particular? I only ask, as your URL ends in "comments/", which is a little bit confusiing. If you wish to draw attention to a particular comment, then please [edit] and add the URL of the exact comment - you can get the comment's URL by right clicking on the date of the comment on that page. It would also be helpful to quote the comment in your question. However, if you are not referencing a comment in particular, but the description instead then maybe quote the relevant part of the description in your answer.

Comment: Just an accident sory

Comment: Ah OK, I thought it might be [this comment by `dipkid`](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3468254/comments#comment-6750743), as it is the only one that *seems* to be mentioning firmware: `blah blah .... When I updated from marlin 1 to 2.0.x, ... blah blah`

Comment: I was searching for answer in coments and forgot to go to the main page

Comment: Ok, cool, yes I see now, `STEP 3 : FIRMWARE`.  Hmmm...

Comment: I don't think that this firmware is needed. cuz all the used commands exsist in older marlin.

Comment: Oh, i know why it's needed. It says that we need to change configuration.h and configuration_adv/h

Comment: Yeah, if you change either of those then you'll need a recompile and then upload the new code to the board. It isn't terribly difficult to do, just follow the steps carefully...

Comment: Can you sugest some tutorial maybe?

Comment: If your question has just boiled down to "How to update the firmware?" then this question probably will help: [Updating Marlin Firmware - Step by Step Guide](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/12153/4762). If it *does* help you, then maybe/probably, your question is a duplicate of that question. If there is something, that the linked question  does not help you with (i.e. something Ender-3 specific), then please [edit] your question to include details about what you need help with. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, Marlin 2.x is not necessary you could use 1.1.9 as well, but, you do need to flash a newly configured firmware as this hardware change is not standardly supported by the current firmware on your printer.