# Is it possible to upgrade the CR10-S Pro to CR10-S Pro v2?

Tags: creality-cr-10, hardware

What I really want to do is to upgrade hardware components to support 'print recovery' after a power outage.

Comment: That's an option you need to [activate in the firmware](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/Configuration_adv.h#L1067).

Answer (score 1):

Print recovery can be achieved by changing the firmware.

Here is some information on how to do that: [Marlin documentation](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M413.html)

Also, this another stackoverflow post about that: [Stackoverflow Post](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10571/how-to-activate-power-loss-recovery-in-marlin)