# Extruder increase temperature

Tags: safety, thermistor

I bought a month ago the Artillery Genius. Everything was pretty good until today, I was printing a test cube and it stopped pulling out filament, when I looked the temperature it was -15 °C, a few seconds after the thermistor sensor broke and got stuck on the extruder creating a little bit of smoke. I had bought a thermistor sensor and a heater cartridge original replacement. I changed both and turn the printer back on. As soon I turn it on the extruder start to increase the temperature, almost 300 °C and then change to -15 °C. I checked the connections multiple times, I even change the sensor with another one, but nothing works. I checked the boards, cables but everything looks great. Don't know what else can be. I already contacted customer support but just want to look for another opinion while waiting for there answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your printer does seem to have a firmware problem and lack important safety features - it should have stopped the moment it went 300°C measurement, beeped like hell, and shut down with an error message about Thermal Runaway Protection. **Immediately stop using the printer!**

Before you try to print again, you need to make a proper firmware for your printer, one that has both [Mintemp, Maxtemp as well as Thermal Runaway Protection actiive](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8466/what-is-thermal-runaway-protection?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C21.9164) and flash that. While setting up your firmware, make sure you use the right temperature table for your thermosensor. How to do that is detailed [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/12153/updating-marlin-firmware-step-by-step-guide9).