# CR-10 S Pro bed heating problems

Tags: heated-bed, creality-cr-10

I've had my bed continually heat up and not stop. I have replaced the SSR and replaced it with an identical-looking one and also replaced it with a MOSFET.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to 3DP. Please take the [tour](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Please list details about your make and model of printer this is, what flavor and version of firmware you're using, and any other information that can help us give you a helpful answer.

Comment: Does it report accurate temps? Sounds like the temp sensor is out.

Comment: In that case [TRP](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/8466/what-is-thermal-runaway-protection) is not active, else it wouldn't keep heating, and firmware should be updated before even continuing.