# Does anyone know a site where you can download straight up G-code files?

Tags: g-code

Is there any known site where you can input your 3D printer's information and it will show you all G-code files uploaded to that site and would have a download button? If not, it's not a huge deal. It's just that I can't find my computer, therefore can't use a slicer.

Comment: Have you tried an online slicer? For example [Kiri:Moto](https://grid.space/kiri/)

Comment: It seems to be working ok so far. But I haven't found how to download the sliced model. I have tried online slicers, but normally I have to then have a 3D addon to wirelessly connect instead of just downloading the file

Comment: Say, I have the Voxelab Aquila X2, which is pretty much the same thing as the Ender 3, as the Ender 3 is open source. Is it okay to select the Ender 3 on the slicer since Aquila isn't on the list?

Comment: You could try it but make sure that the machine settings are the same as the Aquila. If this works out for you, please post your own "answer" and experience in case anyone else comes across this question in the future.

Answer (score 7):

This is generally not a good idea. Your slicing needs to be reasonably tuned to your specific printer. You’re going to have a hard time finding files to start with, and you may have a very bad time if it’s set up for a material different from yours.

So, frame challenge: don’t do that.

Answer (score 4):

### Uncontrolled G-code can be a (medium) security risk.

As we already elaborated [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/18725/8884). In general, [you shouldn't use G-code from a website](https://youtu.be/RKdsp2vrmag), unless you really know what you do.

### Prusaprinters/printables.com

Printables.com, formerly Prusaprinters, allows uploading G-code that does not contain commands that can alter settings. This blocks the `M50x` [family](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/11440/8884) (esp. [M500](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M500.html), [M501](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M501.html), [M502](https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M502.html)) and several other codes (M509, M400, M304, M303, M30) that are easily weaponized to destroy or at least alter printers. By disallowing these commands, *some* damage can be mitigated, but not all: The site does **not** detect G-code that would for example ram your hotend into the bed - and most printers don't have crash detection to stop *that*.

Comment: It's printables.com now.

Comment: @kosteklvp old person me forgot^^

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps go to your printers manufacturers or resellers site. They may have g-code. I got some g-code files along with my printer. So I assume they must be available somewhere.